# Python - Remove duplicate from dataframe for specific values stored in list

Tags: dataframe, list, duplicates, drop-duplicates

I am working with a dataset where the dataframe contains mulitple duplicates for entries. The entries whose duplicates I need to remove are stored in a list. I can't seem to find a way to remove the duplicates in the dataframe. The methods I have tried so far only remove it from the query or filtered list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using:
data[data['Barcode'].isin(dup_list)].drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)